# How to pass the class name reference to edit text which is inside static method in android

Tags: android, static, android-edittext

I have a static method and inside that method I am creating a edit text dynamically.

```
 Here is the code,

public static void done() {
 EditText[] editText = new EditText[dynamiclen];
   for (int n = 0; n < dynamiclen; n++) {
       editText[n] = new EditText(clasname.this);
    ......
  }
```

When I use this code, I am getting error in classname.this saying it can't get a reference. I even tried changing to clasname.class.getName().this but still I am not able to resolve it. Any help would be great

Comment: Your class extends Fragment OR Activity ?

Comment: Activity @HardikJoshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new EditText()` requires **`Context`** not class name

so you can modify your method like below

```
public static void done(Context context) {
 EditText[] editText = new EditText[dynamiclen];
   for (int n = 0; n < dynamiclen; n++) {
       editText[n] = new EditText(context);
    ......
  }
```

Comment: If you are calling from `Activity` then **done(ActivityName.this)** , if you are calling from `Fragment` then **done(getActivity())**

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

Calling:

```
done(this);
```

method definition:

```
public static void done(Context c) {
//...
}
```